# Understanding Scope In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why is it that the 'this' keyword in the printActions function below can access the 'actions' array, but the 'this' keyword in the anonymous function inside the forEach loop, cannot access the 'first' name property?

```
var person = {
    first: "Steve",
    actions: ['run', 'swim', 'bike'],
    printActions: function () {
         this.actions.forEach(function (action) {
            var str = this.first + " likes to " + action;
            console.log(str);

        }); //end forEach
    }//end printActions function

};// person object
person.printActions();
```

Comment: Because the `this` is set on per-call basis*, and in this very case you don't help runtime understand what context that function belongs to.

Comment: Two simple solutions: (1) Use arrow function syntax for the `forEach` callback, or (2) append `.bind(this)` to the closing brace of that function.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097) that I posted some time ago.

Comment: Excellent thanks all.