# 'setTimeOut' calls in JavaScript 'for' loops, why do they fail?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Let me clarify my question. I'm not asking how to make the following code work. I am aware that you can use the let keyword or an iffe that captures its own value of `i`. I just need clarification on how the value `i` is accessed in the following code. I read the following blog post about how it is that the following code does not work. [Blog post](http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside)

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*i);     // 6 6 6 6 6
}
```

The writer claims that the code will not work, because we are passing the variable `i` as a reference instead of a value. That is, instead of providing the value of `i` per iteration we provide the variable to the callback in `setTimeout` as a reference which. In effect, when the loop terminates and callbacks fire, we will have reference to the variable `i` which will be 6. Is this how it works?

Here is my understanding. My understanding is that we are not "passing" anything to the callbacks of the `setTimeout` function, when the loop is executed. We are merely setting up the asynchronous calls. When the closure callback functions do execute, they then look for the variable `i` based on lexical scoping rules. That is, the closures look in the scope were the callbacks have closure over, which again, in this case would be 6 since it is done after the `for` loop completes.

Which one is it, does the function resolve the value of `i` to 6 based on the variable being passed as a reference on each iteration or because of lexical scoping?

Comment: interestingly enough, you still get 66666 if you setTimeout with 0ms pause!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry That's because JS is single threaded. Timeouts are added to the message queue when the timer fires (i.e. the pause is only a minimum delay). MDN has a great article on [the Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Zero_delays)  where you can read about it

Comment: @Kiren; vg, so we wait for the for...loop queue to clear before the sT's are executed, by which time `i` is 6, unless we use closure.

Comment: you can use `setTimeout(console.log(eval(i)));`

Comment: "*they then look for the variable i based on lexical scoping rules.*" - how would that be possible without a **reference** to said lexical scope? (Of course, whether the reference is to a whole scope or an individual variable, and when the "lookup according to rules" is done, are implementation details and subject to optimisation).

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes, but `eval()` should be avoided in 99.99999% of all use cases - certainly this one.

Comment: There is a reference to the scope.. I'm asking about a direct reference to the variable i...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are correct that lexical scoping is the cause of this behavior. When the timer functions run (which will be after the currently running code completes), they attempt to resolve `i` and they must look up the [scope chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097) to find it. Because of lexical scoping, `i` exists only once in the scope chain (one scope higher than the timer functions) and, at that point, `i` is `6` because, at that point, the loop has terminated.

The `var` keyword causes variables in JavaScript to have either function or Global scope (based on where that declaration is). In your code, `var i` causes the `i` variable to exist Globally (because your code is not inside of a function) and each timer function must resolve that same, single `i` when they eventually run. Since the timer functions won't run until the loop is done, `i` is at its last value (6) that the loop caused it to be.

**Change `var i` to `let i` [to create block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for `i` to solve the problem.**

`let` creates block scope for the variable. Upon each iteration of the loop, you enter the loop block again and a separate scope is created for `i` that each timer function gets to itself.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*i);
}
```

Comment: for this very reason, i have stopped using var completely.

function scoped variables are not the norm when it comes to most c syntax style languages.

as the answer says, let enforces block scope.

Comment: let is also not hoisted either for reference to the OP.

there is a lot of internal baggage associated with var. be careful when using it.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the solutions. I just wanted clarification on how the value of `i` is resolved. Is it resolved throw lexical scope? When the callback functions are fired do they look for the value of `i` through lexical scope. Since the callbacks have closure over the variable `i` in the outside scope, does the value of `i` get resolved lexically. Meaning that the callback function will first look for the value within it's scope and then within the outside scope? Thanks

Comment: @HugoPerea Yes, JavaScript uses lexical scoping. Closures are a byproduct of this.

Comment: What do you mean by "references". That's my question. When you say that each call back references the same variable `i` does that mean that when the function executes it does not need to look up the variable throw lexical scope because it already has a reference to it.

Comment: @HugoPerea No. It must look up the scope chain to resolve `i`. This is what lexical scoping means. Let me change the word "reference" to "resolve".

Comment: Ahh that's all I wanted to know. Thanks

Comment: @simon [`let` and `const` are also hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572)

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: Regardless of what the others in that article say, hoisting requires both declaration /and/ initialization.  vars and lets are both initialized as undefined if given no value, however only var is able to be accessed prior to its declaration.

Here is a reference: https://dmitripavlutin.com/variables-lifecycle-and-why-let-is-not-hoisted/

Comment: Example to parse in your browser:  z = 5; console.log(z); let z;

If let was hoisted, the console.log() would output it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Please limit edits to corrections. The use of a capital "G" when referring to Global scope is quite common and was my intent.

Comment: @Bergi It states in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for `let`: *"In ECMAScript 2015, let bindings are not subject to Variable Hoisting, which means that let declarations do not move to the top of the current execution context."*

Comment: @ScottMarcus Apparently [MDN is inconsistent in its usage of the term "hoisting"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let$compare?to=1259455&from=1250513).

Comment: @Bergi Or, you might just say that there was an error in their docs and they fixed it.

Comment: up'ed. The first paragraph is perhaps the most satisfyingly concise and clear I've read and is, unedited, easily applied to the never-ending variations of this same question.

Answer (score 5):

Let me explain with your code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*i);
}
```

At the moment the function `setTimeout()` was triggered, the variable of i will be equal 1,2,3,4,5 as you expected, till **the value of i increases to 6** and stop the for-looping.

```
   var i = 1;
   setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*1);
   i++;
   setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*2);
   i++;
   setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*3);
   i++;
   setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*4);
   i++;
   setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*5);
   i++;
   // Now i = 6 and stop the for-looping.
```

After a period of time, the callback of `timeout` will be triggered, and do console log **value of i**. Have a look above, as I said, the value of i was 6 already.

```
    console.log(i) // i = 6 already.
    console.log(i) // i = 6 already.
    console.log(i) // i = 6 already.
    console.log(i) // i = 6 already.
    console.log(i) // i = 6 already.
```

The cause is the lack of ECMAScript 5: `block scope`. `(var i = 1;i <=5 ;i++)` will create a variable that will exist in the whole function, and it can be modified by the function in the local scope or closure scope. That's the reason why we have `let` in ECMAScript 6.

It can be fixed easily by changing `var` to `let`:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000*i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how this works and all I just need help understanding the part I asked about.