# Understanding nested callbacks and scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I understand there is a lot of documentation and courses on callbacks. I have read a number of those resources, but for this particular problem I don't understand what is going on. And, I think help with this particular problem will help me understand callbacks better.

In short I do not understand why I can access 'ext' in a part of the main 'readFile()' function, but I can't pass it into functions within that function, ie the 'filterData()' function.

Thanks for your help in understanding this.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const dir1 = process.argv[2];
const fileType = process.argv[3];  
const whenDone = function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
  for(i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
    }
  }
}

let arr = [];


function readFile(dirName, ext, callback) {
  fs.readdir(dirName, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
      // ext and data are defined here:
      console.log(ext, data);
      function filterData(ext) {
        // ext and data are not defined here?
        console.log(ext, data);
        return data.filter(function(files) {
          return arr = files.includes(ext);
          console.log(arr);
        });
        return callback(null, arr);
      }
  });
}




readFile(dir1, fileType, whenDone);
```

Comment: I don't see where `filterData` is called

Comment: Probably because you defined ext as an argument to the function which makes it a local variable and overrides any outer scope variables with that name. But... how do you even get there, i do not see a call to `filterData()` or it used as a callback

Comment: May be this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: You're mixing function definition and function call here. Parameter values are defined at the function call, not when a function is defined.

Comment: Thank you for this article!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in the nested function (`filterData`), you declare an argument (essentially a local variable) with the same name (`ext`) that already exists in the higher scope (`readFile`), so, for the duration of the `filterData` function, `ext` refers to what is passed to it, not the `ext` that was passed to `readFile`. This is called ["hiding" or "shadowing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript) and happens when a smaller scope declares an identifier that is already declared in a higher scope.

I've written about this **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097)**.

If you simply change the name of the nested function's parameters and make sure that within the nested function you refer to those parameter names, it will work:

```
// The parameters of a function essentially become local variables
// to that function. The names you give will exist throughout that
// function's scope.
function readFile(dirName, ext, callback) {
  fs.readdir(dirName, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err, null);
    }
    console.log(ext, data);

      // To avoid shadowing/hiding name the nested function's
      // arguments something that doesn't conflict with existing
      // identifier names in the higher scope.
      function filterData(ext2) {
        // Now, there is no collission:
        console.log(ext2, data);
        return data.filter(function(files) {
          return arr = files.includes(ext2);
          console.log(arr);
        });
        return callback(null, arr);
      }
  });
}
```

Here's a simple example:

```js
var x = 10;
var y = 20;

function foo(){
  var x = true; // <-- This x shadows the one from the higher scope
  console.log(x,y); // true 20, not 10, 20
}

foo();
console.log(x,y);  // 10 20 because the scope of foo is not available here
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm definitely a Node and callback novice and had no idea about "hiding" or "shadowing". But it makes obvious sense now.

Comment: @NathanBoaldin JavaScript is "lexically scoped" and, if you ask me, understanding the ins and outs of that concept will unlock a deep understanding of the language. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a ton for the extra explanation and documentation! Super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining param name `ext` within the nested function, which shadows the upper scope `ext` parameter. So you can change that to something else, and you will have the upper scope `ext` param access.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help!