# Why can we access window.document property without specifying window object?

Tags: javascript

As a JavaScript newcomer I see a lot of magic which isn't explained in books. For example, why can I write

```
document.getElementById('one');
```

When `document` is a property of `window`? From what I've read in books, we need to write

```
window.document.getElementById('one');
```

If document would be regular object like any object we would create by ourselves.

---

What allows us to omit `window` parent object while working with `document` property?

I googled this, but I couldn't find an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window` is the Global object in a browser and **[because of the way scope works in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097)**, the Global object will always be the last place that is searched for something. So, omitting `window` is OK because it will wind up being found at the end of the "scope chain".

`document` is a property of `window` and, as such, you do not need to qualify it with `window` for it to be found because when the browser reaches `window` and still hasn't found what it's looking for, it will look at the properties of `window` and find `document` there.

Comment: Not enough information. `document` is a property of `window` but we cannot use it if `window` is `undefined` or becomes `undefined` (just like webpack). In that case, we want to mention about `this` instead.

Comment: @BehindTheScene I don't think that any of that is directly relevant to this question. It's tangental.

Answer (score 0):

`window` represents the browser's window. 
All global JavaScript objects, functions, and variables automatically become members of the window object.

`document` is also a property of global object and hence can be accessed as `window.document` or `document`.

For more information, you can refer [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp)

Comment: *All global JavaScript objects, functions, and variables automatically become members of the window object.* That's not true at all. The JavaScript objects are "native" or "built-in" to the JavaScript runtime. They are not part of the BOM. And `document` is **not** *also* a Global. It is a property of a Global.