# Window object properties behavior

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, window-object

When we have normal javascript objects, we can access there properties by using a syntax like `objectName.proprtyName`. If we just use `propertyName` only, then we will get an error as below -

```js
const myObj = {
  userIdName : "John"
};

console.log(myObj.userIdName); //John
console.log(userIdName); //error "Not defined"
```

However, in the case of in-built `window` object, we can use both `window.propertyName` and `propertyName` alone as below -

```js
console.log(window.alert);
console.log(alert);

//both return same result
```

What exactly is responsible for this behavior of the `window` object? Can we replicate the same behavior for any explicitly built object like the object in the first snippet? (Although nobody would want to pollute the global scope, but I just have this query)

**Edit** - I have received comment that this question is a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274492/why-can-we-access-window-document-property-without-specifying-window-object). This question is very much similar to my answer except one difference - I am looking for a way to replicate the same globally accessible behavior of the `window` object.

Comment: [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) could be used for that, but it’s not recommended. `window === globalThis` ([spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-globalthis), [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)) in the browser; that’s basically what’s special about it.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+why+can+window+properties+be+accessed+globally) of [Why can we access window.document property without specifying window object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50274492/4642212).

Comment: A similar behavior may be possible to replicate in the future using the [Realms API](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-realms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is responsible for this behavior of the `window` object?

JavaScript has two major types of *environment records* (a construct to "hold" name -> value associations): a [declarative record](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-declarative-environment-records) and an [object record](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-object-environment-records).

A *declarative environment* record stores those association in an implementation specific manner. This is the most common type of environment record and is created when you call a function for example.

An *object environment record* uses, as indicated by the name, an actual JavaScript object as the "backend". That means every entry in that environment becomes a property of that "binding object" and vice versa.

The *global environment* uses such an object environment and that binding object is available via `window` in browsers.

> Can we replicate the same behavior for any explicitly built object like the object in the first snippet?

It is possible with the deprecated [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) still exists and creates an object environment record using the provided object as a binding object. From the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-with-statement):

> The `with` statement adds an object Environment Record for a computed object to the lexical environment of the running execution context. It then executes a statement using this augmented lexical environment. Finally, it restores the original lexical environment.

```js
var obj  = {foo: 42};
with (obj) {
  console.log(foo);
}
```