# New to callback functions (passing a callback as parameter)(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, callback

Newbie question here.

I am trying to understand callback functions better.  Reading about them here, i though i grasped the idea.

```js
    function greeting (name, callback){
      console.log(`Greetings ${name}`);
      callback();
    };

    function timeOfDay (time){
      console.log(`How are you this fine ${time}?`);
    };

    greeting ('Brad', timeOfDay('evening') );
```

Output

```
How are you this evening?
Greetings Brad
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Can  someone please explain why the output is in this order?  What does this error refer to and why does it appear even though the code has finished?

I first did a simple callback function along the same structure and it worked fine.

Thanks in advance
Brad

Comment: `timeOfDay()` ***calls*** the function. If you want to pass the function itself, you need to omit the `()`.

Comment: `timeOfDay('evening')` returns `undefined` as you have no return statement ... and `undefined` is not a function - you'd want greeting ('Brad', function() {timeOfDay('evening');} );

Comment: @deceze but then how dou you pass `'evening'` ?

Comment: or you can use like this  `("Brad", timeOfDay.bind(this, "evening"));` that way you bind a context to the function and not call it instantaneous

Comment: Hey - good well formulated question. Note that you can embed HTML, CSS and JS in stackoverflow - which makes it much easier for us to answer.

Comment: @JeremyThille  done  :)

Comment: Here goes, as promised :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, but when passing `timeOfDay("evening")`, you aren't actually passing that function as the callback. That is a function invocation and it runs immediately and whatever the return value of that is, is what is passed to the `greeting` function invocation as the second argument. Since `timeOfDay` doesn't return anything, you are passing `undefined` to `greeting`.

The solution is to pass an actual function, not the result of invoking one (unless that result is, in fact, another function), to `greeting`, and one way we can do that is by wrapping the `timeOfDay()` function call in an anonymous function declaration, like this:

```js
function greeting (name, callback){
  console.log(`Greetings ${name}`);
  callback();
};

function timeOfDay (time){
  console.log(`How are you this fine ${time}?`);
};

greeting ('Brad', function() { timeOfDay('evening') } );
```

Another technique is to use the **[`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)** method, which returns a copy of the function you've called it on, but the context that the function will execute in is configurable by you, based on the first argument you pass to `.bind()`. This is a very useful technique, but requires a good knowledge and understanding of scope and context, which you can read more about **[in another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097)**:

```js
function greeting (name, callback){
  console.log(`Greetings ${name}`);
  callback();
};

function timeOfDay (time){
  console.log(`How are you this fine ${time}?`);
};

greeting ('Brad', timeOfDay.bind(this,'evening') );
```

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed explanation.  Another piece of the callback puzzle is placed.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, when you do something like this:

`greeting ('Brad', timeOfDay('evening') );`

you will be calling the `timeOfDay` function instantaneously.

To avoid that you can use one of these options:

1. Wrap your function call in an anonymous function, like said in another answers.
2. You can omit/remove the parenthesis, like this `greeting('Brad', timeOfDay);` (this avoid instant function call, but you'll lose your parameter `"evening"` and the error will persist).
3. You can `.bind()` a context to the function, in the example below, I'm binding `this` as the context to the function, that way it's not going to call the function instantaneously.

take a look:

```js
function greeting (name, callback){
  console.log(`Greetings ${name}`);
  callback();
};

function timeOfDay (time){
  console.log(`How are you this fine ${time}?`);
};

greeting ('Brad', timeOfDay.bind(this, 'evening') );
```

Further reading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: What do you mean when you say "you can omit the parenthesis"?

Comment: I feel like you're sending him down the wrong track with bind.

Comment: @ScottMarcus as said in the first comment in the question. Just like `greeting ('Brad', timeOfDay);`  But this way the parameter will be lost and error will persist.

Comment: I think you should clarify that in your question as many people (like me) may read your answer but not necessarily all the comments to the OP.

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thanks for your answer.  Still got lots to learn about the intricacies of the callback function.