# what is function scoped variables (var) and block scoped variables in es6?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, block, var

I am new to javascipt as I have started learning js now, I am pretty confused with `var` that is said to be function scoped and block scoped;

If so then how do we access them outside of that function!? lets say i want to use it from another class (I don't know maybe by creating some object or whatever) (I guess we can't create objects here! because as it is a functional programming based language I guess!:( )

```js
var y = "global";

if (y === "global") {
  var y = "block-scoped";
  console.log(y); // expected output: block-scoped
}

console.log(y); // expected output: block-scoped
```

Comment: The code logs as you expected.

Comment: yes but i had some other doubts and it cleared now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is not said to be function scoped.

Variables declared with `var` can either be function or Global scoped.

- If the declaration occurs within a function, then the variable is
  scoped to that function.
- If the declaration occurs outside of a function, then the variable is
  scoped Globally.

If a variable is declared with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), then it has block level scope. [A block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) is delimited by `{}` or if those symbols are not present, the enclosing function or, if not in a block or a function, then Global.

[I've written another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097) that discusses scope and the scope chain in much greater detail and should help in answering your coding scenario.