# Get id of parent div from clicked form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Okay so I have multiple forms on the page, the difference is their `id`, also each one has a parent box, all of which also have a different `id`.

The html of one of the box:

```
<div class="center-block" id="box2">
    <form action="/login" id="form2" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input id="Name" name="Name" type="hidden">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

I submit the forms with ajax, and what I want to do is find the `id` of the box that had its form submitted.

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data !== "0") {
                        window.location.href = data;
                    } else {
                        //Here I would like to alert the id of the parent box.
                        //Something like this:
                        alert($(this).closest('div').attr('id'));
                        //Which returns undefined                        

                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("No idea what went wrong");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any idea how I would do that?

Comment: `$(this).parent('div').prop('id');`.

Comment: "this" is the success function. you have to save "this" from the event into a variable.

Comment: You need to master javascript's [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the JQuery **[parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** method:

```
alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
```

Also, as others have pointed out, you have a different issue in that `this` isn't pointing to the `form` when you use it in the success callback. You should cache that value and then use the cache variable. You can read more about how `this` works in JavaScript **[in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41497007)** of mine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        // Cache the object that "this" is bound to because
        // in the success function, the invocation context 
        // changes and "this" won't point to the same object 
        // it does now.
        var theForm = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data !== "0") {
                    window.location.href = data;
                } else {
                    //Just use the JQuery parent() method with the cached object
                    $(theForm).parent().attr('id')


                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("No idea what went wrong");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: still undefined :/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, any reason why I should use `.parent` over `.closest`?

Comment: @m_bale, `parent` method is more efficient than `closest`.

Comment: @m_bale Both can work. `parent()` does exactly what you are looking for, while `closest()` allows you to search for an "ancestor" that matches a certain selector.

Answer (score 5):

`$(this)` won't work in success callback. `$(this)` is relative, the scope of `$(this)` will be of success callback. You need to assign a variable first & then use it in success callback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            var curr_form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('url'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data !== "0") {
                        window.location.href = data;
                    } else {
                        //Here I would like to alert the id of the parent box.
                        //Something like this:
                        curr_form.closest('div').attr('id')
                        //Which returns undefined                        

                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("No idea what went wrong");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! Can you somehow explain to me how it now works?

Comment: @m_bale Inside the success callback, `$(this)` refers to the object of the ajax, not the form's `$(this)` which it was bound to.