# javaScript - pass object as function argument

Tags: javascript, function, object

I want to use an object as function argument. When I define an object outside fucntion and then pass it as an argument, it works fine:

```
var obj = {
  a: 0
}

function foo(obj){
  console.log(this.obj.a); 
}

foo() //0
```

But when I pass an object directly, it doesen't work:

```
function bar({a: 0}){
  console.log(this.arguments.a)
}
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

An object doesent seem to be a legal argument. How do I fix it?

Comment: *this* is context only !!! Dont use it for accessing variables.

Comment: You're mixing the function invokation and function definition. Arguments are passed in function invokation, they are not getting their values in the argument list of the function definition.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding the way parameters and variables in javascript work. Reusing the same name for the parameter and variable name is confusing you. You can pass an object as a parameter but not define it in the function definition.

Comment: You are making a wrong deduction. You are not even passing a value to `foo` in the first example. So `this.obj` cannot actually refer to the *parameter* `obj`. Use `function foo(){ console.log(this.obj.a); }` (note: no parameter) in the first example and you'll that it still works the same. So `this.obj` has nothing to do with the parameter `obj`. You need to do two things: [Learn more about functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html) and [learn how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: It's a pity none of the answers here make an attempt to explain context, as that might help clear a lot of the confusion.

Comment: @Andy My answer does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "this" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195970/what-does-this-mean)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ES6 supports parameters destructuring.
You can use:

```
function bar({a}){
    console.log(a)
}
```

However usually it is useful when you have multiple parameters:

```
// you pass option to a function old way
function oldOps(option){
    var protocol = option.protocol;
    var method = option.method;
    var port = option.port;
    console.log(port);
}
// new and more readable way
function newOps({protocol, method, port}){
    console.log(port)
}
```

Only old IE doesn't support it.

> But when I pass an object directly, it doesn't work:

```
function bar({a: 0}){
  console.log(this.arguments.a)
}
```

You cannot pass parameters this way or make initialization of a default parameter. Furthermore, `this` in you case will refer to the parent object, so `this.arguments.a` doesn't make sense as in most cases it will refer to `window` object.

With parameters destructuring you may use **default parameters**, so your code will look:

```
function bar({a = 0}){
    console.log(a)
}
bar({}) // 0
```

Still, any efforts to call it without parameter will result in error as JS will try to resolve property of `undefined`

You may use another default parameter assignment to resolve the issue. When you really want to call `bar()` without parameters and have default value for destructured parameter you should use something like:

```
function bar({a = 0} = {}){/*...*/}
```

Just don't forget that **it is not widely supported by browsers**, so you will have to use transpiler to convert your ES6 code one supported by browser.

Most popular transpilers are [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org).

Comment: While this is right, I don't see how this helps the OP.

Comment: @FelixKling I added details

Comment: I still think the OP has a fundamental misunderstanding how function calls work (read the question carefully). Talking about destructuring is not helpful in this case, even though they accepted the answer. I question whether they understood what this is about.

Comment: Your functions will throw an error if called with no arguments because it does not specify a default value. It should be `function bar(a = {a:0}){...`

Comment: @scott marcus no it shouldnt. Then a would be an object.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are wrong. Just try `x=({a})=>{console.log(a)};x({a:1});` in a browser console ;)

Comment: Actually, I've tried your posted answers (with no arguments passed) and get an error. Have you tried them? Additionally, try this: `x=({a})=>{console.log(a)};x();`. If you set a default value for the argument, you won't get an error when no arguments are passed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Now I tried `function bar({a}){
    console.log(a)
}
bar({a:1})` ans it works as expected. I think you misunderstand something in my answer.

Comment: You are not reading my comments. Try: `function bar({a}){ console.log(a) } bar();`. When you call any of your posted functions (**with no argument**), they will fail. This is why you need to set up a default value for the parameter.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think you misunderstand my answer. I never suggested to use `bar` without parameters.

Comment: No, but I am suggesting that because the OP's code shows an attempt to call `foo()` with no arguments. Answers should address the questions. Your code exposes a bug. You should add the default value to patch it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is not a bug. It is intended behavior. Furthermore, OP was not about calling `bar` without parameters as far as I can see ;)

Comment: Then it doesn't address the use case of the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154475/discussion-between-v-andrew-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score 5):

Cause *this* has nothing todo with the variables passed. Dont use it here. Simply do:

```js
     function bar({a = 0} = {}){
       console.log(a)
     }

     bar({});//0
     bar();//0
     bar({a:10});//10
```

Comment: And in FF. Jonas, you should test it.

Comment: @andy yes i should. However im AFK 90% of my day, so im not always able to do so.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers have actually tried to address the issue here so I thought I might have a go.

You ask: "I want to use an object as function argument." And yet your first example doesn't show you doing this. You are **not** passing in an object as a function argument. What you *are* doing is declaring a variable under `window` (assuming this is browser code) and then logging that variable's value to the console. *Because* `this` is **context** and `this` is defined by the way the function is *called*, in this instance the context is `window` and so your code works.

You second code example compounds the errors you're making in the first example. `arguments` is scoped locally to the function. It doesn't need `this` in front of it. And you can't access it like it's an object because [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is an array-like structure. You would access it like this: `arguments[0].a` assuming you're passing the object into your function like this: `bar({a: 1})`.

JavaScript context and scope can be a very difficult concept to get your head around. I'm a pretty seasoned JS developer and it still catches me out occasionally, so don't be disheartened. [This article is very good at explaining context (and function scope)](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) and I think you would benefit from reading it.

Answer (score 2):

First, it appears that you are combining how to declare a function parameter with how to call a function and pass it a parameter with this code:

```
function bar({a: 0}){
  console.log(this.arguments.a)
}
```

Next, when accessing arguments, just use the parameter name, not `this`. `this` is used to reference the invocation context object, not function parameters. The invocation context object is essentially the object that was responsible for causing the function to be invoked in the first place. It can also point to an object that was explicitly set to replace the native object that would have been the context object. And, in the right circumstances, it can point to the Global (`window`) object or be `undefined`. `this` is typically confusing for a lot of JavaScript developers. Here's **[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969)** to more information on `this`.

So your code should be:

```js
// Declare the function and set up a named parameter
function bar(someObj){
  console.log(someObj)
}

// Call the function and pass an object literal:
bar({a: 0});
```

Now, you can in fact supply a default value for a function and this would be how to do that:

```js
// Establish an object with an `a` property with a value of "Hello"
// as the default value of the function's argument
function bar(obj = {a: "Hello"}){
  console.log(obj);
}

bar();  // Default value of parameter will be used
bar({a:"Goodbye"}); // Passed value will be used
```