# What are the differences between fun({var}) and fun(var)?

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to ask you about the differences of the codes below. They both work but I could not find the differences

`({ name })`

```
function swimmer({ name }){
    return {
        swim: () => console.log(`${name} swam`)
    }
}
```

`( name )`

```
function swimmer( name ){
    return {
        swim: () => console.log(`${name} swam`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46224977/10994570

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it was really useful.

Comment: Glad it helped you, have a happy code day :) @ZenCode