# Is there a simple way to understand .bind of JavaScript in plain english?

Tags: javascript

I have seen the docs.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind 
but I just don't seem get .bind in pure vanilla javascript as a concept.

Can someone please explain.  I have seen code examples, but this topic I'm struggling to understand what it actually means.

This question I do feel is different, because I want to understand it from a conceptual view point, not just code examples.  For example, if I had a garden object, and I added a function called make apples, it would generate 1 apple.  If I had a function called make oranges, it would return 1 orange.  What does bind mean, in a simple context please.  JavaScript has been very difficult for me and my progress is slow and I'm struggling to get the bind concept.

Comment: In order to understand `.bind` you should understand how `this` works in JavaScript. Read this chapter from "You don't know JS" https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` allows you to change the value of `this` in a function. `bind` also creates a new function.

```js
var cat = {
 name: 'cat',
  whatIsThis(){
   console.log('this is ' + this.name)
  }
}
var dog = {
 name: 'dog',
  whatIsThis(){
   console.log('this is ' + this.name)
  }
}

cat.whatIsThis()// this is cat

dog.whatIsThis()// this is dog

var func = cat.whatIsThis.bind(dog)

func()// this is dog

cat.whatIsThis()// this is cat
```

Comment: I understand part of this code, and tested in the console and it works exactly like you said. thank you btw.  The part I struggle understanding is ..

Why is it that when we do var func = cat.whatIsThis.bind(dog)
and then when calling func()
why isn't var func() both cat and dog, why is it only dog?  That part is flying over my head.  Thank you again.

Comment: Oh i see, do you mean why there aren't 2 log statements? `cat.whatIsThis` does not call the function (hence no `this is cat` in the log), it only serves as a reference so that i can assign it to the variable `func`. Once i've assigned `cat.whatIsThis.bind(dog)` to `func`, it no longer remembers anything about cat, even though that's where it came from. It's important to know the difference between `whatIsThis` and `whatIsThis()`. The former is a function reference (you can save to variable, or pass into another function as an argument), the latter is a function call.

Comment: Ok I think I finally actually understand both this and bind!.  THANK YOU for this moment.!

Comment: Glad i could help. Isn't learning fun :D

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `this` in JavaScript is (generally) bound to the object that caused the function that contains the word `this` to be invoked. Often times, that object that is bound to `this` is not the object that we would like for `this` to be bound to. A full understanding of `this` binding is essential to really understand JavaScript in depth. Now, I did say that `this` is "generally" bound to the object that caused the function containing `this` to be invoked, but there are many reasons why that may not turn out to be the case. I've written about `this` and what object it will bind to under various circumstances **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969)**.

The **[`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)** method allows us to first make a copy of a function that contains the word `this` and additionally allows us to override the normal `this` binding and bind any object we like to the `this` occurrence in that newly copied function.

It allows us to control the object that `this` is bound to while giving us a completely new function to work with.