# Unityscript class extend variable scope

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm not all that well versed in JavaScript and I've got a scope problem that I can't find a reference on:

```
class a
{
  var CommonNameVar;
}

class b extends a
{
  var CommonNameVar;

  function Something(){
     CommonNameVar = "somevalue"; 
  }
}
```

How do I specifically reference `CommonNameVar` in b and not a (i.e. reference a specific scope of variables)?

It turns out that I'm also not familiar with unityscript and I've made a rather cardinal mistake of assuming that just because this has a .js on the file, that this is javascript (sound like an old sketch from Bob Newhart).

I'll post a new question formatted correctly for the context and declare this one dead.

Comment: This is totally invalid syntax. You cannot put `var`s or `function`s in a `class`. Did you mean properties (created in the constructor) and methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide `CommonNameVar` from the scope it is declared in. But, to make it available to `b`, you need to create it as `this.CommonNameVar` so it becomes an instance property and will inherit, otherwise, it's just a local variable and won't inherit.

The `this` keyword ensures that you'll always get the value of the property that is associated with the instance.

And, your syntax needs a bit of work as classes declare properties within them, not just "loose" elements.

So, with the code below, when an instance of `a` is made, `this` will reference one instance and `CommonNameVar` will be `something` and when an instance of `b` is made, `b.CommonNameVar` will also be `something` (because of inheritance), until/unless `b.Something()` is executed, in which case `b.CommonNameVar` will then be `somevalue`, while `a.CommonNameVar` will remain `something`.

```
class a {
  this.CommonNameVar = "something";
}

class b extends a {

  this.Something =  function() {
     this.CommonNameVar = "somevalue"; 
  }
}
```

`this` can get considerably more tricky depending on your code structure and you can read about that **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969)**.