# this refers to inside function on javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a = function foo(){
    this.confusing = 'hell yeah';
    function boo(){
        this...
    } 
}
```

In function `boo()` which call inside of `foo()`, will `this` be defined for `foo()`element?

Comment: `this` will reference `window` within `boo()`

Comment: you are assigning name to function twice

Comment: Hi Dina and welcome to StackOverflow. Angular is just JavaScript so the same rules apply there as they would to vanilla JavaScript. Take a few minutes and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) which should answer this question for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969

Comment: fixed grammar and formatting

Comment: fixed grammar and formatting

Comment: `this` will reference `window` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `boo` function, `this` will reference the `boo` function object, or "window" if you will. This is similar to the stacking of scopes in python, if you're familiar with that.