# What's the difference in writing the empty arrays inside the method instead of writing them as object parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What's the difference in writing the empty arrays inside the method,

```
var example = {
    calcMethod: function() {
        this.array1 = [];
        this.array2 = [];
    }
};
```

instead of writing them as object parameters?

```
var example = {
    array1 : [],
    array2 : []
};
```

to eventually fill them with data.

Comment: None of this is valid Javascript.

Comment: Your question is really about the use of the `this` keyword. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969). But your specific syntax `let = object` is invalid. It should be something like `let o = {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the illegal javascript syntax I'll answer your question.

The difference is that `calcMethod` must be called before `array1` and `array2` are defined in the first snippet. Otherwise they'll be `undefined`:

```js
let object1 = {

calcMethod: function() {
        this.array1 = [1];
        this.array2 = [2];
    }
}

let object2 = {
    array1: [3],
    array2: [4]
}


console.log(object1.array1);  // undefined
console.log(object1.array2);  // undefined

object1.calcMethod();

console.log(object1.array1);  // [1]
console.log(object1.array2);  // [2]

console.log(object2.array1);  // [3]
console.log(object2.array2);  // [4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SaniSinghHuttunen I fixed the syntax so anyone with the same question can have a valid answer.