# Javascript: Bind/unbind function behavior

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I bind a function with the parent `this` passed in `thisArg`, I can't unbind the same named function expression, but without it I can unbind the function itself. Why is that?

This works:

```
choicesList.addEventListener("click", function() {

    const self= this;

    document.addEventListener("click", function checkClick(e) {

        if (!e) e = event;
        if (!self.contains(e.target)) {

            document.removeEventListener("click", checkClick);
        }
    }, false);
});
```

This doesn't:

```
choicesList.addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.addEventListener("click", function checkClick(e) {

        if (!e) e = event;
        if (!this.contains(e.target)) {
            document.removeEventListener("click", checkClick);
        }
    }.bind(this), false);
});
```

Comment: *I do can unbind* ?????

Comment: it's because the declared `checkClick` function `!==` the function resulting from `checkClick(){}.bind(this)`, which means `removeEventListener()` fails to find a match

Comment: note that `Function.bind() !== Function.bind()`. Every call to `.bind` creates another object or function (your second example `checkClick.bind(this) !== checkClick`). In order to remove an event listener you MUST pass in the same object (function) and options used to create the event listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is issue is that calling `bind()` on a function  returns a new instance of that function:

```js
function someHandler() {
  alert('hi');
}

const someHandlerBinded = someHandler.bind(document);


// Returns false, seeing as these are different instances of the function
console.log( someHandlerBinded === someHandler );
```

By setting an event handler directly, via the result of `bind()` as you are in your second block of code, this causes a new instance of that function handler to be passed to `addEventListener()`. This in turn means that the subsequent attempt to removing this handler on line:

```
document.removeEventListener("click", checkClick);
```

will fail, seeing that the the defined function `checkClick` is not the same as the actual handler function used for that click event (ie the new function instance returned from `function checkClick(){ ... }.bind()`)

One way to resolve this might be the following:

```
choicesList.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Declare the bound version of the click handler
    const boundClickHandler = function checkClick(e) {

        if (!e) e = event;

        if (!this.contains(e.target)) {

            // Removing the result of bind, rather than the declared 
            // checkClick handler
            document.removeEventListener("click", boundClickHandler);
        }
    }.bind(this)

    // Adding the result of bind as you currently are doing
    document.addEventListener("click", boundClickHandler, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this` is in a function that is nested within another function and the nested function doesn't have the same [invocation context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097) as the outer one. The first one works because you are caching the object that the outermost `this` is referencing and you are then able to correctly reference it in the inner function.

You can read more about the volatility of `this` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969).