# How to get "this" object in to a callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

How do I get this into a callback?

Started out with this, worked.

```
$('#grid').w2grid({
  name : 'grid',
// Lost of setup
  onMenuClick: function(event) {
    $.getJSON('?json=json&action=E&id=' + event['recid'], function(data) {
//    do some work
    });
    this.reload();
  },
});
```

Then to only call reload if the request worked.

```
$('#grid').w2grid({
  name : 'grid',
// Lost of setup
  onMenuClick: function(event) {
    $.getJSON('?json=json&action=E&id=' + event['recid'], function(data) {
//    do some work
      this.reload();
    });
  },
});
```

Of course "this" is no longer references the object I want to access.

Or how would I gain access the parent object?

Comment: arrow function or store the `this` in another variable and use that variable.  This question is a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) your `this` inside the callback.

Note: Beware of any side-effects. Apparently you don't seem to need the new `this` inside the callback.

Try:

```
$('#grid').w2grid({
  name: 'grid',
  onMenuClick: function(event) {
    $.getJSON('?json=json&action=E&id=' + event['recid'], (function(data) {
      this.reload();
    }).bind(this));
  }
});
```

When arrow-functions are [available](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions), I'd suggest to use them rather than binding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
let parent = this;
$.getJSON('?json=json&action=E&id=' + event['recid'], function(data) {
//    do some work
      parent.reload();
    });
```