# javascript: Assign function to a variable fills variable with undefined

Tags: javascript, object, scope

It's kinda basic, but its giving me some headaches:

I'm assigning a function to a variable, then I call a function inside the first function from the variable.

When I assign the function to the variable its filled with undefined, so when I call the inner function I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

This is the code I'm working on:

```
(function () {

  function Sum() {

    this.result = 0;

    this.getCurrentSum = function getCurrentSum() {
      return this.result;
    }

    this.add = function add(add_number) {
      this.result += add_number;
    }

  }

  var s1 = Sum();  // here s1 is undefined
  var s2 = Sum();  // here s2 is undefined

  s1.add(10);  // here cannot execute add of undefined crash
  s1.add(20);

  s2.add(30);
  s2.add(5);

  // must print 30
  console.log(s1.getCurrentSum());

  // must print 35
  console.log(s2.getCurrentSum());

}());
```

I can change the code in the Sum function, but I can't change the rest of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want `Sum` to be a *constructor function*. You call constructor functions via `new`, not directly. So:

```
var s1 = new Sum();
var s2 = new Sum();
```

The reason you were getting `undefined` in `s1` and `s2` without `new` is that `Sum` doesn't do `return x` anywhere, so the result of calling it is the value `undefined`. But when you use `new`, the result of the `new` expression is the object that was created.

FWIW, there's another problem with `Sum`: You're missing out `this.` in a couple of places (also a couple of semicolons, though Automatic Semicolon Insertion will add them for you):

```
function Sum() {
  this.result = 0;

  this.getCurrentSum = function getCurrentSum() {
    return this.result;
// −−−−−−−−^^^^^
  };

  this.add = function add(add_number) {
    this.result += add_number;
// −^^^^^
  };
}
```

JavaScript isn't like Java or C#, `this.` isn't optional.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> wat if I can change the Sum function or anything inside the function but I can't change the var s1 = Sum();calling?

In that case, you'd make `Sum` a *builder* function and have it return an object, like this:

```
function Sum() {
  return {
    result: 0,
    getCurrentSum: function getCurrentSum() {
      return this.result;
    },
    add: function add(add_number) {
      this.result += add_number;
    }
  };
}
```

Live Example:

```js
(function () {

  function Sum() {
    return {
      result: 0,
      getCurrentSum: function getCurrentSum() {
        return this.result;
      },
      add: function add(add_number) {
        this.result += add_number;
      }
    };
  }

  var s1 = Sum();  // here s1 is undefined
  var s2 = Sum();  // here s2 is undefined

  s1.add(10);  // here cannot execute add of undefined crash
  s1.add(20);

  s2.add(30);
  s2.add(5);

  // must print 30
  console.log(s1.getCurrentSum());

  // must print 35
  console.log(s2.getCurrentSum());
})();
```

Normally a builder function wouldn't start with a capital letter (that's essentially reserved for constructor functions), so it would have a name like `createSum` or `buildSum` or similar.

That version of `Sum` is written with ES5-level syntax (actually it's even ES3-level). In ES2015+ it could be a bit more concise:

```
// ES2015+ using method syntax
function Sum() {
  return {
    result: 0,
    getCurrentSum() {
      return this.result;
    },
    add(add_number) {
      this.result += add_number;
    }
  };
}
```

Live Example:

```js
(function () {

  // ES2015+ using method syntax
  function Sum() {
    return {
      result: 0,
      getCurrentSum() {
        return this.result;
      },
      add(add_number) {
        this.result += add_number;
      }
    };
  }

  var s1 = Sum();  // here s1 is undefined
  var s2 = Sum();  // here s2 is undefined

  s1.add(10);  // here cannot execute add of undefined crash
  s1.add(20);

  s2.add(30);
  s2.add(5);

  // must print 30
  console.log(s1.getCurrentSum());

  // must print 35
  console.log(s2.getCurrentSum());
})();
```

Comment: wat if I can change the Sum function or anything inside the function but I can't change the `var s1 = Sum();`calling?

Comment: @Alex Your a bit stuck then because even if you changed the `Sum` to take arguments and return the result of working with those arguments, you'd still have to change the way you call `Sum` so that you could pass in the arguments.

Comment: @Alex - In that case, you'd make `Sum` a *builder* function rather than a constructor function, I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `this` within the `Sum` function, you need to have an instance of that Object constructed. Using the `new` operator to use `Sum` as a ["constructor function"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) will accomplish that.

But, then in `Sum` you declare `this.result` as an instance variable, so you must also refer to it as `this.result` in the other spots in the function as well.

Take a look [at another post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496958/this-does-not-work-properly-in-another-event-im-clueless-as-to-why/41496969#41496969) that talks about `this` and what it does.

```js
(function () {
  function Sum() {
    this.result = 0;
    this.getCurrentSum = function getCurrentSum() {
      return this.result;
    }
    this.add = function add(add_number) {
      this.result += add_number;
    }
  }

  var s1 = new Sum();
  var s2 = new Sum();

  s1.add(10);
  s1.add(20);

  s2.add(30);
  s2.add(5);

  console.log(s1.getCurrentSum());  // 30
  console.log(s2.getCurrentSum());  // 35
}());
```